# How to generate a train-test-split based on a group id?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have the following data:

```
   Group_ID Item_id Target
0         1       1      0
1         1       2      0
2         1       3      1
3         2       4      0
4         2       5      1
5         2       6      1
6         3       7      0
7         4       8      0
8         5       9      0
9         5      10      1
```

I need to split the dataset into a training and testing set based on the "Group_ID" so that 80% of the data goes into a training set and 20% into a test set.

That is, I need my training set to look something like:

```
    Group_ID Item_id Target
0          1       1      0
1          1       2      0
2          1       3      1
3          2       4      0
4          2       5      1
5          2       6      1
6          3       7      0
7          4       8      0
```

And test set:

```
   Group_ID Item_id Target
8         5       9      0
9         5      10      1
```

What would be the simplest way to do this? As far as I know, the standard `test_train_split` function in sklearn does not support splitting by groups in a way where I can also indicate the size of the split (e.g. 80/20).

Comment: what have you tried? using random selection can work.

Comment: @Rob Could you provide an example? I've relied so much on sklearn in the past that I'm completely lost with how to split any other way.

Comment: I can think of two ways but it depends on your complete dataset.  1)Lets say, you have 10 records in dataset then sort the dataset based on groupid and then just use train =  df.iloc[:8,:], test = df.iloc[8:,:]        2) Use a conditional subset. Like make a list of groups . for exam-  a = [5,6]  and use df['groupid].isin(a)

Comment: @AdityaKansal The data is about 4 gb in size. Could I use something like sklearn's GroupShuffleSplit?

Comment: Also you should use K-folding for training and testing. This is where you split you data into k (usually k=10) random sets, you then loop k times and each time you use (k-1) sets to train and 1 to test. (a different one each loop) This will make sure that all data is used to train, test.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I figured out the answer. This seems to work:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit 

splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.20, n_splits=2, random_state = 7)
split = splitter.split(df, groups=df['Group_Id'])
train_inds, test_inds = next(split)

train = df.iloc[train_inds]
test = df.iloc[test_inds]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n_splits=1`? It will still work with `n_splits=2`, but generate an extra split which is never used.

Comment: The number of splits determines the relative sizes of train and test - if you want 50:50 then you need to use n_splits=2, 80:20 use n_splits=5 etc.

Comment: What if we want to split keeping whole groups but at the same time you want to stratify (to keep the same proportion of classes). How do you mix groupwise and stratification splitting?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas here if you want to split only once.

```py
train_ids = (
    df['Group_Id'].value_counts(normalize=True)      # get Group_Id distribution
    .sample(frac=1, replace=False, random_state=0)   # randomize
    .cumsum()                                        # make the shares into cudf
    .pipe(lambda x: x.index[x > test_size])          # get train Ids
)
train_mask = df['Group_Id'].isin(train_ids)
train = df[train_mask]
test = df[~train_mask]
```

With that being said, the main advantage of `GroupShuffleSplit()` (as used in the top answer) is its `n_splits=` argument, which returns multiple splits of the data by simply iterating over the generator. So you can do cross validation on each split. In the following example, `split` is a generator that returns 5 different splits which can be used to evaluate the model.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit 

splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.2, random_state = 0, n_splits=5)
split = splitter.split(df, groups=df['Group_Id'])

for train_inds, test_inds in split:
    train = df.iloc[train_inds]
    test = df.iloc[test_inds]
    # fit a model and get its score
```

---

It should probably be noted that it works best if the groups are evenly distributed. As the following example shows, in the case of an unbalanced dataset, the train set may end up being much smaller (even though `test_size-0.2`):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group_Id': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1], 'value': range(10)})
splitter = GroupShuffleSplit(test_size=.2, random_state=0)
train_inds, test_inds = next(splitter.split(df, groups=df['Group_Id']))
train = df.iloc[train_inds]
train.shape        # (3, 2)
```

In that case, pandas could become very useful. However, unlike the above cases, it will give the specific Group_Ids in a specific way (i.e. deterministic), so only works in special cases.

```py
pct_cumsum = df['Group_Id'].value_counts(sort=True, ascending=True, normalize=True).cumsum()
train_group = pct_cumsum.index[pct_cumsum > test_size]
train_mask = df['Group_Id'].isin(train_group)
train = df[train_mask]
test = df[~train_mask]
```